# How to compare opening hours?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to compare opening hours stored on my server with the current time.

Given the following:

start: 09.00
end:   00.30

I want the result if the store is open or closed. When the current time isn't in the given start and end time the store is closed.

The code i use until now does not work. I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined

```
firebase.database().ref("v3/standalonelist/bars").on('value', function(snapshot) {

    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.content = snapshot.val();
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

        $scope.data1 = [childSnapshot.val()];
        $scope.locations1 = $scope.data1

        $scope.locations1.forEach(function(item) {

        $scope.getMinutes = function(str) {
                var time = str.split('.');
                return time[0] * 60 + time[1] * 1;
              }
              $scope.getMinutesNow = function() {
                var timeNow = new Date();
                return timeNow.getHours() * 60 + timeNow.getMinutes();
              }
              var a = new Date();
              var day = a.getDay(); // 3
              var now = $scope.getMinutesNow();
              console.log(item.opens[day]); // returns 09.00
              var start = $scope.getMinutes(item.opens[day]); // 09.00
              var end = $scope.getMinutes(item.closes[day]); // 01.20
              if (start > end) {
                end += $scope.getMinutes('24.00');
              }

              if ((now > start) && (now < end)) {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                  $scope.open = true; // Store is open
                })

              } else {
                $scope.open = false; // Store is closed
              }
         })
       })
```

Comment: You don't appear to be defining `item.opens` and `item.closes`.

Comment: yes i do. I get the data from firebase. The console.log before the var start returns the correct time.

Comment: Then you should include the data in your post.

Comment: @DanWilson read the comments, i posted the values there.

Comment: Where your error happends? Is item.closes[day] gives you normal log message as well?

Comment: @Antenka yes, the log message runs fine and i get the correct values back

Comment: @olivier, what line gives this error?

Comment: @Antenka var start = $scope.getMinutes(item.opens[day]);

Comment: @olivier, ok. What do you have inside item.opens?

Comment: @Antenka i have an array inside  there. For each day a start time

Comment: @olivier, I know you have the better answer now. But I'm curious what was the problem there :) What if you save the result of item.opens[day] in the temporary variable and then call the $scope.getMinutes with that variable? Makes any difference?

Comment: @Antenka I tried that. Didn't change anything sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making it a little more complicated than it has to be...

```
var today = new Date(),
    open = "Open",
    closed = "Closed",
    display = document.getElementById('display'),
    start = new Date(), end = new Date();

    // Set the opening hour:minutes
    start.setHours(10);
    start.setMinutes(5);
    // Set the closing hour:minutes
    end.setHours(18);
    end.setMinutes(30);

// Check the time based on milliseconds
if (
    today.getTime() >= start.getTime() && 
    today.getTime() < end.getTime()
) {
    display.innerHTML = open;
} else {
    display.innerHTML = closed;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L770r2qk/

You might also want to take into account different days, such as a business that runs from late night to early morning. For that you would also want to use `start.setDate(12)` and `end.setDate(13)`. You then might also want to take into account month changes where you would then use `start.setMonth(10)` and `end.setMonth(11)`.

Those extra features are up to you and I will let you implement them into the example.

Comment: but what if, like stated above: end = 00.30?